# AWK - how to improve this example?

Tags: awk

I have a file:

```
AA
BB
```

This command prints out:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { system("awk '"'"'{print}'"'"' file") }'

AA
BB
```

The same, but in the 'printf':

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { system("awk '"'"'{printf "%s ", $0}'"'"' file") }'

/bin/sh: Illegal option -,
```

How to improve the last command to get the result:

```
AA BB
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("awk '\''{printf \"%s \", $0} END { print \"\" }'\'' file")}'
AA BB
```

or more easily:

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("paste -sd\" \" file")}'
AA BB
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, your question is merely an exercise in curiosity. There are undoubtedly better ways to accomplish whatever you might be trying to do if it's not.

Rather than trying to use complex sequences of open and close single and double quotes which may have odd side effects if they're not paired up properly, you can use variables to represent quotes. By having, in essence, third-level quoting, it makes the code easier to read. The technique below is somewhat analogous to Perl's `q()` quoting.

Set a variable `q` to the octal equivalent of a single quote, then you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{q = "\047"; system("awk " q "{print}" q " file")}'
```

Spacing is up to you - each string segment is concatenated to its adjacent segments.

This is another way that you might find more readable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{q = "\047"; system("awk " q"{print}"q " file")}'
```

Comment: I ask about solution from curiosity only.
I know there are better ways to solve this problem.
Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, don't use `awk`; use `tr`.

```
tr '\n' ' ' file; echo;
```

Or, if you need all that in one pipeline

```
tr '\n' ' ' file | awk 'END { print }'
```

Comment: It thanks but it walks about something other me.

I want to use this command so:

`awk 'BEGIN { system("awk '"'"'{printf "%s ", $0} END { print "" }'"'"'  file") }'`

Comment: @Tedee12345 why do you want to do all that pointless system nonsense?

Comment: I want to use system() from two causes. 1. For educational. 2. I want to use system() in my function.

Comment: @Tedee12345 This is not a function in which `system` is appropriate. 1. It teaches you a bad practice, making it the opposite of educational. 2. You "want" needless complexity?

Comment: I ask about solution from curiosity only.
I know there are better ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it purely in awk you could try something like this:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $0} END { print "" }'  <  aabb.txt
```

Comment: It thanks but it walks about something other me. 

I want to use this command so:

`awk 'BEGIN { system("awk '"'"'{printf "%s ", $0} END { print "" }'"'"'  file") }'`